# Add class in loop attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, class

I want to put a class in multiple attributes if it's in the correct url.

I am entering the case if it is in url and trying to add, the code in the console just says undefined but does not perform the actions.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      document.querySelector('span .price').classList.add("forcehide");
    }
});
```

```css
span.price.forcehide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-details">
  <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> NAme Product </a> 
</strong>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info-details">
  <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> NAme Product </a> 
</strong>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to delete all price?

Comment: [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) return reference to single element, hence loop is not required. You should remove loop and use `classe.className = force; ` otherwise use `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: did not work, I believe he is getting the wrong attribute because from what I realized he made an attribute <span class = "forcehide">                                                Correct is to add in <span class = "price forcehide">

Comment: Use `document.querySelector('span .price').classList.add("forcehide");`

Comment: only works in one, I need to do that on all <span class = "price"> of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Satpal said in the comments, [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method returns just one element.

To get a list of all elements matching the query selector, you should use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.price");
    for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      const span = spans[i];
      span.classList.add("forcehide");
    }
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.price");
    for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
      const span = spans[i];
      span.classList.add("forcehide");
    }
});
```

```css
span.price.forcehide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-details">
  <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> NAme Product </a> 
</strong>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info-details">
  <strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> NAme Product </a> 
</strong>
  <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
    <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```